# Как получить предупреждение компилятора при несовпадении типов данных?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Есть ли способ принудить PL/SQL компилятор сообшить (используя подсказку компиляции или ошибку), что в коде есть попытка присваивания строчного значения в численную переменную?

В некоторых случаях неявное преобразование выполнится и присваивание будет безошибочным, но хочу избежать это присваивание вообще. Хочу всегда, чтобы было как минимум предупреждение при несовпадение типов.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Oracle implicit conversion warning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65575159) от участника [@kovalensue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4121801/kovalensue)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/65575159

Answer (score 4):

Включить предупреждения компилятора для PL/SQL программ можно с помощью команды:

```
alter session set plsql_warnings='enable:all';
```

Предупреждение для неявного преобразования `PLW-07204`, его можно включить отдельно:

```
alter session set plsql_warnings='enable:7204'
/
create table tab (stringval varchar2(100))
/
SQL> create or replace procedure proc is
  2      Num number;
  3      Str varchar2(100);
  4  begin
  5      Num := 10;
  6      select stringval into Str
  7      from tab
  8      where stringval = Num;
  9  end;
 10  /

SP2-0804: Procedure created with compilation warnings

SQL> show errors
Errors for PROCEDURE PROC:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
8/11     PLW-07204: conversion away from column type may result in
         sub-optimal query plan
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ec1fb129e862ddf4629dd8f743564082)

Это предупредит только о неявном преобразовании внутри статических SQL выражений, где оно может быть как справа, так и слева от условного оператора, и тем самым вызвать снижение производительности.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65576343) от участника [@Andrew Sayer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9856176/andrew-sayer)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Нет, это пока невозможно. Если при присвоении значения одного типа данных переменной другого типа данных применимо неявное преобразование (*implicit conversion*), даже если значение приведёт заведомо к ошибке этого преобразованния, то компилятор не считает это ошибкой и не предупреждает об этом.

---

Процитатирую [Тома Кайта](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/on-implicit-conversions-and-more):

> SQL and PL/SQL are very “datatype friendly”. They attempt — whenever possible — to do what you ask them to do. [...] I consider all these *implicit conversions to be bugs in the developed code* [...].

Это пока всё ещё актуально и поэтому, нужно отказатся от "дружественного предложения": "Мы позаботимся о преобразовании за Вас", и где это только возможно - избегать неявного преобразования.

Код ниже компилируется без ошибок и предупреждений, но в нём заложены программные ошибки, которые проявятся:

- стр. 5 - при первом запуске
- стр. 6 - года через два-три, когда DBA решит изменить десятичный разделитель  с `,` на `.`

```
SQL> alter session set plsql_warnings='enable:all';

SQL> create or replace procedure proc authid definer is
  2      n number := 0;
  3      s varchar2 (96) := '0,1';
  4  begin
  5      n := '123a';
  6      n := s;
  7  end;
  8  /
Procedure created.

SQL> show errors
No errors.
```